# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to load a resource file from the */wwwroot/3d_models* folder location.

In the Startup.cs I enabled **app.UseStaticFiles();** and added the following snippet:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, @"3d_models")),
    RequestPath = new AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/models")
});

app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, @"3d_models")),
    RequestPath = new AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/models")
});
```

Under the */wwwroot* folder (in solution explorer), I added the resource file:

[image]

Yet still, I'm getting this 404 error.
Interestingly, when I try to go to the file directly from the browser, I also get the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

#### Update

I found the answer in *[Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1)*.

Comment: Use `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Startup.css`

Answer (score 1):

The folder is called 3d_models whereas the URL is *models/xbox.glt*.

Shouldn't the folder name match where it's looking for it? (or vice versa)

Only parameterless UseStaticFiles will look for assets from webroot. If you pass parameters then by nature it will look for these assets outside the webroot.

That's what appears to be happening in your case as they are looking for a models folder outside the webroot.

NOTE:

Here's a good link explaining Parameter-ed vs Parameter-less call of UseStaticFiles().

*[Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1)*

Comment: the app.UseStaticFiles code should map 3d_models to models.

Comment: if the UseStaticFiles call has parameters then the purpose is to serve / look for files outside webroot .. not within web root.

if you want to look within webroot, then dont pass any parameters

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. Basically, I had to set the mimetype/mapping for the .glb file type.

See *[Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1)*.