# ASP .NET Core .glb file not found whereas the file was copy

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, web

Hello

I want to import a .glb file but when I call it in JS I get an error which tell me that the file isn't found whereas the file was copied.
Here's my files:

```
wwwroot
 /-Assets
 /---Element
 /---Objects3D
 /-----hub.glb
```

Here, the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()    :44353/Assets/Objects3D/hub.glb:1
```

Have you an idea ? 
Thank you !

Comment: What is a GLB file?

Comment: GLB file is a compressed file which stock 3D models

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081107/asp-net-core-3-1-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-o),and see the answer of AlvinfromDiaspar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so with some little investigation I was able to solve my issue, this might help you solve your problem too.

In the server side when setting the UseStaticFiles you should add some options to allow UnkownType files to be accessed.
There are two ways you can solve this. The first is especifying the type of the file that you wish to provide that way. In this case you should do it this way on you **Startup.cs** file, `Configure` function:

```
StaticFileOptions options = new StaticFileOptions { ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider() };
((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)options.ContentTypeProvider).Mappings.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(".glb", "model/gltf-buffer"));
app.UseStaticFiles(options);
```

The second option (and more appropriate if you have more than 1 Unkown file type) is to allow any UnkownTypeFile using a flag on the same StaticFileOptions at the same `Configure` function:

```
StaticFileOptions options = new StaticFileOptions { ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider() };
options.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;
app.UseStaticFiles(options);
```

Also, make sure you are able to access the subdomain directories on you server. If you are not, then you should also include this in your `ConfigureServices` function in the **Startup.cs** file:

```
services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
```

As well as the line bellow on your `Configure` function at the same file:

```
app.UseFileServer(enableDirectoryBrowsing: true);
```

**Note:** This solution is for a server using .Net Core 3.1. If you are using a different version or .Net Framework there might be a different fix.

Comment: Verified that the content works for StaticFileOptions in .Net Core 6.0.

Thanks for this answer.